# Better way to position svg:polygon

Tags: svg

The SVG elements `<line>`, `<circle>`, `<rect>`, `<text>` and , `<image>` allow for positioning by x and y based off of the view port. Furthermore they can also be relatively positioned. Is there any way to accomplish this for `<polygon>` than to wrap it in an `<svg>`? The closest substitute for `<polygon>`, `<path>`, also has this... issue.

Comment: Do you mean something like transform="translate(100,100)" which should work ?

Comment: Define it in your <defs> and then do a <use>?

Comment: @Ian transform(x y) and x/y attributes are not equivalent.

Comment: @MichaelMullany you mean like this... http://jsbin.com/iqEkAsE/2/edit

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on the excellent comment by @Michael Mullany I was able to find a solution to the issue. By putting the polygon or path in side a `<defs>` tag it can be used later on in a `<use>` tag. The `<use>` tag allows for setting of x and y attributes that function the same as the attributes of other simple shapes like `<line>`, `<circle>`, `<rect>`, `<text>`

http://jsbin.com/iqEkAsE/2

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%">
  <defs >
  <path id="Triangle"
    d="M 1 1 L 200 1 L 100 200 z"
    fill="orange" 
    stroke="black" 
    stroke-width="3" />
  </defs>
  <use x="33%" y="33%" xlink:href="#Triangle"/>
  <use transform="scale(-1)" x="-66%" y="-66%" xlink:href="#Triangle"/>
</svg>
```

It would be nice to be able to scale the shape dynamically by setting the width and height property of the `<use>` to a percent but it can still be scaled with a transform.

Comment: glad I could be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Use transformations (translation, rotation, scale), that is the correct way to do it.

The other shapes allow you to use a point defined by x,y coordinates because that's just a part of the shape definition (i.e. how do you define a circle, you need the center point and the radius).

In theory you could position an element using its bounding box, however the bounding box is not "settable" (there is no `setBBox` method), there is only `getBBox()`

Comment: the x and y values in a transform are integer values based on the viewport, which only appears to be pixels because of the defaults for the viewport. While the values for an x or y attribute is a <coordinate>: e.g. '5px', '10cm', '15%'. Transform and x/y attributes are not equivalent. That's why i have been wrapping <polygon> and <path> in an <svg> tag.